# Xcode 12(beta 4) not recognizing Header files while building in simulators

Tags: cocoapods, ios14, xcode12

Xcode12 unable to recognize headers, where as when i run in real device no errors.

[image: here]

Comment: Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @nOObiOS no not yet.

Comment: for me it fixed when I changed Build Active Architectures only to YES in Debug mode

Comment: @nOObiOS I tried that didn't work for me :(

Comment: If you have pods installed, try to change this settings for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

After so many days, finally figured it out, I have VALID_ARCHS in build settings. By removing that and adding arm64 to excluded architectures solved my problem.